# Custom reduce operation in boost.mpi

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, mpi

I'm having troubles getting a custom reduce operation compiling with the boost.mpi library. I'm trying to do an elementwise add of two `std::vector`. The operation works fine when I use to add two vectors together but when I try with `mpi::reduce` I get the error "no known conversion from 'int' to 'const std::vector' for 1st argument".

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

template <typename T>
struct elementwise_add {
    std::vector<T> operator()(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b) const {
        std::vector<T> result(a.size());
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<T>());
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;
    int N = 10;

    std::vector<int> a(N,1), b(N,1);
    auto op = elementwise_add<int>();
    auto c = op(a, b); // works fine

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::vector<int> sum(N,0);
        mpi::reduce(world, a, sum, op, 0); // errors
    } else {
        mpi::reduce(world, a, op, 0);
    }
}
```

Compiled with:
`mpic++ -O3 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/ -I. -lboost_mpi-mt -lboost_serialization-mt test.cc -o test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles fine with boost 1.54. However, in version 1.55 two overloads of `reduce()` were introduced:

```
template<typename T, typename Op> 
void 
reduce(const communicator & comm, std::vector<T> const & in_values, Op op, 
       int root) 
{
  reduce(comm, &in_values.front(), in_values.size(), op, root);
}

template<typename T, typename Op> 
void 
reduce(const communicator & comm, std::vector<T> const & in_values, 
       std::vector<T> & out_values, Op op, int root) 
{
  out_values.resize(in_values.size());
  reduce(comm, &in_values.front(), in_values.size(), &out_values.front(), op, 
         root);
}
```

This means that when you call `reduce()` and provide `std::vector` as input (as you do in your code), pointers to the data will be passed on.
Note that if `reduce()` is given pointers, it will by default operate on a per-element basis. You thus shouldn't pass an operator for combining vectors, but one for combining `ints` (such as `std::plus<int>()`).

The following code should work for you (boost version >= 1.55):

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main() {
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;
    int N = 10;

    std::vector<int> a(N,1);

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::vector<int> sum(N,0);
        mpi::reduce(world, a, sum, std::plus<int>(), 0);
    } else {
        mpi::reduce(world, a, std::plus<int>(), 0);
    }
}
```

If you want your code to work also with earlier version of boost (< 1.55), you will have to pass the pointers to the data yourself. Like so:

```
    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::vector<int> sum(N,0);
        mpi::reduce(world, &a.front(), N, &sum.front(), std::plus<int>(), 0);
    } else {
        mpi::reduce(world, &a.front(), N, std::plus<int>(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there was something fishy going on. I should have looked at the source code instead of the doc :-)